# Ant exec resultproperty is not working

Tags: ant, build

I am calling a batch file using an Ant `exec` task and setting the result in `resultpropery`. But the return value never comes to Ant. Below is my code

```
<property name="BuildErrorCode" value="abc"/>
<exec executable="cmd" resultproperty="BuildErrorCode" failonerror="false"
      dir="C:\workspace\build\">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="cmake_cross_compile.bat"/>
</exec>

<echo message="Error Code:=${BuildErrorCode}" />
```

I exit my batch script by:

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

When the script runs, i always get `abc` as value instead of return value from batch file. My batch file returns `2` for now and I have to stop the build

I want to do the following:

1. If the return value is <> 0 then i have to make the build fail which is not happening now.

Any idea how I can get he return value and make the ant build fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `exec` task `resultproperty` will capture the exit code of the cmd interpreter.  The way you are calling exit in the batch file though is not terminating cmd, it is only exiting the script.  The exit code from cmd will be unaffected, and stay zero.  If you simply remove the `\b` option of the exit command you will terminate the interpreter as well and see the exit code you supply propagated.

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit %errorlevel%
```

To fail, you could use a [`fail` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html), perhaps something like this:

```
<fail message="cmake_cross_compile.bat exited non-zero">
    <condition>
       <not>
         <equals arg1="${BuildErrorCode}" arg2="0"/>
       </not>
     </condition>
</fail>
```

Or you could set `failonerror="true"` in the `exec` task to fail immediately.

Comment: OK another thing is, what can i do in ANT Build.xml with the retun value to make the ANT build report as failure

Comment: Thanks Martin. the `exit %errorlevel%` works now. I am able to get the value in ANT.`<fail>` works perfectly fine. I am able to report the build as failure which is what i wanted. Thank you both

Comment: The downside of this is that if you run the batch file directly for testing it will terminate your shell.  you could use an if and an arg in the batch file to select \b when ant calls it and normal exit when not.

Comment: The exit code from `cmd` should be the exit code of the last script that ran, so `exit /b` and `exit` should have exactly the same effect.  Any idea what Ant is doing that breaks this?

Answer (score 8):

If you run the build script in verbose mode (`ant -v`), you will notice the line

```
Override ignored for property "BuildErrorCode"
```

Essentially once an ant property has been set its value cannot be changed.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492002/override-ignored-for-property) has details.

A possible workaround is to not `declare` the property.

```
    ...
    <!--property name="BuildErrorCode" value="abc"/-->
    <exec executable = "cmd" resultproperty="BuildErrorCode" failonerror="false" dir="D:\work">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="cmake_cross_compile.bat"/>
    </exec>
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Raghuram. now atleats i get value 0 even though i need to get 2. I will check batch file again. thanks