# Jenkins pipeline build using Jenkinsfile is not failing

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have a [declarative](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) pipeline stage like below,

```
stage('build') {
    steps {
        echo currentBuild.result
        script {
                try {
                    bat 'ant -f xyz\\build.xml'
                } catch (err) {
                    echo "Caught: ${err}"
                    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
            }
        echo currentBuild.result
    }
}
```

I expect the pipeline to fail since the build is failing with below message.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\...\build.xml:8: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\...\build.xml:156: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\...\build.xml:111: Problem creating jar: C:\...\xyz.war (The system cannot find the path specified) (and the archive is probably corrupt but I could not delete it)
```

currentBuild.result is null both the time i print it.
Is the ant call wrong? 
Why is the return status not caught automatically by pipeline?
Could the ant call be not returning failed status?

I tried catchError instead of try..catch and still the build failure is not caught.

```
catchError {
    bat 'ant -f xyz\\build.xml'
}
```

Comment: Looks like ant doesn't propagate the error to the pipeline. Perhaps this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395597/propagating-exit-code-from-execd-batch-file-back-to-ant.

Comment: Thank you haschibaschi, the page in your comment gave me some pointers to try, namely `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`. I used it in one of the solutions i listed below in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add "call" keyword to ant call like below, this propagates the exit code from ant to batch call.

```
stage('build') {
    steps {
        bat 'call ant -f xyz\\build.xml'
    }
}
```

There is another solution using batch scripting, see below,
- **Jenkinsfile**

```
stage('build') {
    steps {
        bat 'xyz\\build.bat'
    }
}
```

- **build.bat**

```
call ant -f "%CD%\xyz\build.xml"
echo ELVL: %ERRORLEVEL% 
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 ( 
    echo ABORT: %ERRORLEVEL%
    call exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
) ELSE (
    echo PROCEED: %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

In this build.bat, if you don't use call keyword, only the first command will be executed and the rest will be ignored. I adapted this directly to ant call in pipeline and it worked.